# Next power of 2 in fortran

Tags: fortran, bitwise-operators, fortran90, fortran77

Simple question. I'm converting some C++ to fortran and cannot figure out how to get the next power like this:

```
inline int
pow2roundup (int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        ++x;
    --x;
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    return x+1;
}
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
INTEGER :: x

IF (x == 0) x = x+1
x = x-1
x = x OR RSHIFT(x, 1)
x = x OR RSHIFT(x, 2)
x = x OR RSHIFT(x, 4)
x = x OR RSHIFT(x, 8)
x = x OR RSHIFT(x, 16)
x = x+1
```

But it didn't like any of these lines. I don't think bitwise OR operator can be used like this. Some help here would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I think i may have figured this out but I'm not 100% sure. Please see below - those OR lines should be edited to use IOR like this?

```
x = IOR(x,RSHIFT(x, 1))
x = IOR(x,RSHIFT(x, 2))
x = IOR(x,RSHIFT(x, 4))
x = IOR(x,RSHIFT(x, 8))
x = IOR(x,RSHIFT(x, 16))
```

Is this right?

Comment: Re: OR lines - that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm now back at the ice fortress with access to a Fortran compiler so here's an answer to replace my earlier comment.

As you seem to have figured out the Fortran operator `.or.` (the points are significant) operates on variables of type `logical`. The intrinsic function `ior` does a bitwise inclusive `or` on integer operands which it treats as bit vectors. I haven't tested your code but it looks OK.

However you seem to have taken the old adage that *A real programmer can write Fortran in any language* and turned it on its head to *A real programmer can write any language in Fortran*.  I mean, what you have written is correct (if it is correct that is, I really mean that it seems to be a correct term-by-term translation of the C++ into the nearest equivalent Fortran) but it's not what a Fortran programmer would write.  (Sure, other Fortran programmers are welcome to disagree on this.)

If I (a representative Fortran programmer) was working on a machine with an implementation of binary floating-point arithmetic I'd use the intrinsic function `exponent` for finding the next power of 2 greater than a given number.  Like this:

```
integer :: given_number
...
write(*,*) exponent(real(given_number))
```

which will write the next power of 2 greater than `given_number`.  If `given_number` is itself a power of 2 this will give the next power of 2.  And take a little care at the end of the range of the kind of integer you are using.

Comment: My code seems to be working as intended but I've only been coding on fortran recently and didn't even know EXPONENT existed. Thanks - I'm interested to try this way as it seems quicker.

Comment: And an `ieee_selected_real_kind(..., radix=2)` in that `real` may make things even more convincing.

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is a bit old, but I'd like to add an answer I consider the most straightfoward and idiomatic:

```
ibset(0, bit_size(n) - leadz(n))
```

---

All of those are *instrinsic* functions for bit manipulation of integers. Also, if n is itself a power of 2, it returns the next power.

`bit_size(n)` gives the number of bits in the integer model of `n`. If the argument is of type `integer(kind=int16)`, it returns 16.

`leadz(n)` counts the number of leading zero bits of a number. E.g. `leadz(19) == 11`, because `19 == B'0000_0000_0001_0011'`.

`ibset(i, pos)` sets 1 to the bit in the position `pos` on the number `i` (from right to left, zero-based). Thus, `ibset(0, 16-11) == 32`, because `32 == B'0000_0000_0010_0000'`.

P.D.: Care should be taken if`n > huge(n) / 2`. Fortran does not have unsigned integers, hence if the first bit of an integer is set, it is a negative number. For 16 bits, for example, the maximum representable positive number is `2 ** 15 - 1 == 32767 == B'0111_1111_1111_1111'`. There is no next power of two after 16384, given that `B'1000_0000_0000_0000' == -32768`.

Comment: It may be (very slightly) worth noting that `integer(int16)` refers to an integer with a _storage size_ of 16, if one exists.  This doesn't mean that there are necessarily 16 bits in the numeric model of such an integer.

Comment: Provided that both `bit_size` and `leadz` refer to variables of the same integer kind, the expression still works for any ultimate integer type selected, independent of the numeric model or radix (except if the kind parameter you choose is not soported by the underlying system; in this case it won't compile)

Comment: Oh yes, I wasn't suggesting there'd be a problem.  Just that `bit_size(1_int16)` needn't necessarily have result `16`.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues, should `ibits` not be `ibset`? As I understand from documentation, `ibits` extracts `len` bits from `i` starting at `pos` (your examples are missing the required `len` argument in that case), while `ibset` returns `i` (all zeros with i=0) with bit position `pos` set to 1 - and this is what I understand the intention of your answer to be.

Comment: Good catch, @jbdv. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are exactly right. 
The following  is probably the fastest way to do it. 
(assuming that you want exact powers of 2 to go up
to the next exact power of 2.)

```
pure integer  function shift_up(x_in)
    integer, intent(in)::x_in
    integer::x
    x=x_in
    x = ior(x,rshift(x, 1))
    x = ior(x,rshift(x, 2))
    x = ior(x,rshift(x, 4))
    x = ior(x,rshift(x, 8))
    x = ior(x,rshift(x, 16))
    x = ior(x,rshift(x, 32))
    x= x + 1
    shift_up = x
 end function shift_up
```

Using log base 2 (as below) takes about 14 times longer.

```
pure integer  function shift_logs(x_in)
    integer, intent(in)::x_in
    real ::x
    x = x_in
    shift_logs = 2**(floor(log(x)/log(2.0))+1)
end function shift_logs
```

Comment: high performance Mark, I think probably means,             2**exponent(real(i)). Which is not bad but takes about 3.7 times longer than shift_up

Answer (score 0):

You can write fortran code this way for next power of 2. For example if we provide number `7`, this will give `8(2^3)`. If we provide `9` it will give `16(2^4)`.

```
program power2
    implicit none
    integer::num,output

    integer::i,nmin,nmax
    integer,parameter:: N =3
    num = 17
    nmin = 1
    nmax = 2
    do i=1,N       !! N checkes the range (2^N)
        if  (num>nmin .and. num<=nmax) then
            output=nmax

        end if
        nmin = nmin*2
        nmax = nmax*2
    end do
    write(*,*)"num,output_value",num,output
end program
```